# Travis JDK 6 version

Tags: version, travis-ci

From build output it appears that Travis is using version 1.6.0_34 of the JDK:

java version "1.6.0_34"

Is there any way to get this upgraded to version 1.6.0_45?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have version numbers confused; 
Travis uses OpenJDK 6 (for security reasons the unmaintained Oracle version is not available) and the OpenJDK project has the 1.6.0_37 release planned for tomorrow.